# Reverse gear and marble noise

Tags: noise, mazda, manual-transmission, mazda-3

On my Mazda3 sometimes my gear shifter doesn't seem to throw all the way, and whenever I engage the clutch I hear what sounds like marbles. What could be the cause of this? I can put car in neutral and retry the shift and it's fine after that.

Comment: I am ancient, we use to call that "grind me a pound Mrs Folgers" The clutch is not fully releasing, you need to have a professional look at the clutch system.

Comment: @Moab "drain gearbox and refill with teeth" was a comment we used - I've also been around the block...

Comment: @Moab How severe is this? The clutch seems okay in other scenarios, but I'm a newbie at manual so I may just not be noticing any bad behavior. What else can I look for to determine if its definitely the clutch? I thought perhaps it could be something with the gear shifter itself, a bearing?